# A Distracting Puzzle

Tags: riddle, knowledge, poetry

> One, three, four, two; seven, eight, six, five.
>
> Size, we're told, doesn't matter.
>
> But if it did, there's the answer!
>
> ---
>
> Four solid, yet light. Four airy, yet heavy.
>
> One stands crooked, one has a twin.
>
> One's got an eye, like one in a picture.
>
> ---
>
> But there is another! A big one!
>
> This one's not like the others:
>
> That which holds it all together.
>
> ---
>
> A few more attributes, our mystery has:
>
> Two belts! One of them holds a member
>
> That was once thought to be another.
>
> *It isn't!*

**What is the name of the collection of members that this poem describes?**

Comment: The title is vaguely associated with the subject at hand, but not very closely. Don't spend too much time on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The planets.

> One, three, four, two; seven, eight, six, five.
>   Size, we're told, doesn't matter.
>   But if it did, there's the answer!

> There are eight planets, hence the first clue, which are labeled in order of increasing size.

> Four solid, yet light. Four airy, yet heavy.
>   One stands crooked, one has a twin.
>   One's got an eye, like one in a picture.

> Jupiter has an eye. Uranus and Neptune are alike, essentially twin planets. Neptune, I believe, has an extreme tilt on its axis relative to its orbital plane.

> But there is another! A big one!
>   This one's not like the others:
>   That which holds it all together.

> The sun is not quite like the rest of the planets, but its gravity is what forms the solar system.

> A few more attributes, our mystery has:
>   Two belts! One of them holds a member . 
>   That was once thought to be another.
>   It isn't!

> The asteroid belt, and the other belt (Kuiper Belt) of debris and exoplanets that extends far out past Neptune, which includes Pluto (once considered to be a planet, now no longer).

Comment: First word of line two.

Comment: I considered sorting them by size, but...assuming they line up with their distance, that's not their relative sizes; for instance, Three is the largest of One, Two, Three, and Four. And five, six, seven, eight, by size, are sorted Eight, Seven, Six, Five.

Comment: I misspoke on the second array - Seven, Eight, Six, Five is the proper ordering. Still, Three is absolutely larger than Four, Two, and One.

Comment: Mercury is the first smallest, Venus the third, Earth the fourth...

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood then. I took them to mean that, for example, Earth is Three, and then we organized them by size; so I read "Mercury, Earth, Mars, Venus" as the sequence. Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: No problem! If you edit that into your answer I can give you the checkmark.

Comment: No problem! @SirDerpy